# Ruby open uri download via proxy

Tags: ruby, http, open-uri

I don't know how to download data from URL using open-uri and active proxy.

I used this code:

```
    proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy("??????????????????????")
    proxy.start('http://www.example.com') { |http|  
    puts open(strURL).read 
    }
```

but Ruby returned error: c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:644:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

What's wrong ?( I don't want to use HTTP)(

Comment: You want to tunnel a non-HTTP protocol through an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Please read: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI/OpenRead.html#method-i-open

Answer (score 5):

Try this :

```
require 'open-uri'
p = open('http://www.example.com', 
          proxy: URI.parse("http://190.72.158.80:8080")
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer comments above are not helpful, they do not show how to specify the proxy info as part of OpenURI open() method. This SO thread does answer the question:
[Ruby Proxy Authentication GET/POST with OpenURI or net/http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043046/ruby-proxy-authentication-get-post-with-openuri-or-net-http)