# Ruby Proxy Authentication GET/POST with OpenURI or net/http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, open-uri, net-http

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and trying to use `open-uri` to get a url and try posting using `Net:HTTP`

Im trying to use proxy authentication for both:

Trying to do a `POST` request with `net/http`:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'
http = Net::HTTP.new("google.com", 80)
headers = { 'User-Agent' => 'Ruby 193'}

resp, data = http.post("/", "name1=value1&name2=value2", headers)
puts data
```

And for `open-uri` which I can't get to do `POST` I use:

```
data = open("http://google.com/","User-Agent"=> "Ruby 193").read
```

How would I modify these to use a proxy with HTTP Authentication

I've tried (for open-uri)

```
data = open("http://google.com/","User-Agent"=> "Ruby 193", :proxy_http_basic_authentication => ["http://proxy.com:8000/", "proxy-user", "proxy-password"]).read
```

However all I will get is a `OpenURI::HTTPError: 407 Proxy Authentication Required`. I've verified all and it works in the browser with the same authentication and proxy details but I can't get ruby to do it.

How would I modify the code above to add http authentication properly? Has anyone gone through this atrocity?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
require "open-uri"
proxy_uri = URI.parse("http://proxy.com:8000")

data = open("http://www.whatismyipaddress.com/", :proxy_http_basic_authentication => [proxy_uri, "username", "password"]).read
puts data
```

As for Net::HTTP, I recently implemented support for proxies with http authentication into a Net::HTTP wrapper library called [http](https://github.com/tarcieri/http). If you look at my last pull-request, you'll see the basic implementation.

**EDIT:** Hopefully this will get you moving in the right direction.

```
Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy_uri.host, proxy_uri.port,"username","password").start('whatismyipaddress.com') do |http| 
  puts http.get('/').body
end
```

**EDIT 11/24/2020**: `Net::HTTP::Proxy` is now considered [obsolete](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-Proxy). You can now configure proxies when creating a new instance of `Net::HTTP`. See the documentation for [Net::HTTP.new](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-new) for more details.