# Opening a non-HTTP proxy URI on https domain using OpenURI

Tags: ruby, https, proxy, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm behind a proxy and I must get an HTTPS webpage to collect some information, but OpenURI returns an error: "Non-HTTP proxy URI".

This is the issue:

```
> yadayada@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test/lib$ ruby JenkinsTest.rb 
/home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:257:in `open_http': Non-HTTP proxy URI: https://web-proxy.yadayada:8088 (RuntimeError)
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:736:in `buffer_open'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:211:in `block in open_loop'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `catch'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:209:in `open_loop'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:150:in `open_uri'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:716:in `open'
from /home/yadayada/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/open-uri.rb:34:in `open'
from JenkinsTest.rb:6:in `<main>'
yadayada@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test/lib$
```

This is the code I'm running:

```
  1 require 'rubygems'
  2 require 'nokogiri'
  3 require 'open-uri'
  4 
  5 # Request the Jenkins webpage
  6 @jenkinsWebPage = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://yadayad.yada.yada.com:8443"))
  7 
  8 # Prints the received page
  9 puts @jenkinsWebPage
```

The proxy has no login/password.

Any ideas?

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043046/ruby-proxy-authentication-get-post-with-openuri-or-net-http

Comment: I've checked it before, but there's no authentication on the proxy I'm using; There's going to be an issue with that jenkinsWebPage afterwards due to an invalid self-signed certificate on the Jenkins server, but I don't think that this is the issue that open-uri is complaining about at the moment, I'm actively searching for a solution to this for weeks now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've found out how to get the page, but I had to switch open-uri for net/https, also, I set OpenSSL to VERIFY_NONE, since it's a self signed certificate (company server):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/https'
require 'openssl'

class JenkinsTest
    # Request the Jenkins webpage
    def request_jenkins_webpage
        uri = URI.parse("https://https://yadayad.yada.yada.com:8443")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        response = http.request(request)
        @@page = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
    end

    def print_jenkins_webpage
        puts @@page
    end
end
```

It looks ugly, if anybody finds out a better way to put this, please edit this post, but as of now, it's working fine.